# Cannot get grub to load the right image in a VM

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, kvm-virtualization

I have an Ubuntu image created with the following:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -b focal-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img test.qcow2 20G
```

It comes up and cloud-init works.   I now install a new kernel with

```
apt install linux-generic
```

And that seems to bring in the initrd and the kernel I want to use:

```
$ ls /boot
System.map-5.4.0-1062-kvm     grub                          vmlinuz
System.map-5.4.0-109-generic  initrd.img                    vmlinuz-5.4.0-1062-kvm
config-5.4.0-1062-kvm         initrd.img-5.4.0-1062-kvm     vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic
config-5.4.0-109-generic      initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic  vmlinuz.old
efi                           initrd.img.o
```

The problem is I cannot get grub to load the generic kernel.   According to the docs all I need to to is edit /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=3
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then do an `update-grub` and reboot.  I have tried every possible value for GRUB_DEFAULT but it always ends up ignored.  The original KVM kernel always boots.  It seems like there is some parameter somewhere that is in conflict.  Am I doing the right thing or missing a step?

UPDATE:  I would still like to solve this, but I discovered that there is an Ubuntu release that uses cloud-init and the generic kernel.  So I am using that now.  So if you need this use:

```
focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.img
```

instead of

```
focal-server-cloudimg-amd64-kvm.img
```